# Transistor with floating base

Tags: transistors

How does a transistor work in a circuit if its base has no connection to any part of the circuit?
How can I find its working state?

Thanks in advance

Edit:
Yes, this is a BJT. My assumption is that the transistor's base potential is negligable in this case.
The working mode of it is similar to a voltage-controlled switch, using only its breakdown effect(s).

Comment: *This is a general question...* Irrelevant, the way how a component is **used** in a schematic is relevant so a schematic is needed. Depending on the polarity and value of the voltage across the transistor, the function of that transistor in that circuit will vary.

Comment: And what about the other wo nodes? Also floating?

Comment: c'mon... if it has a base is a BJT. Usually, if it's an NPN with collector more positive than emitter because that is how you hook it up as an ampli or even as a switch. "Can you tell me what time is it?" "Yes I can". "So tell me". "You did not specify the longitude". "Here, now". "You did not specify if you want in daylight saving and if you want the time in arabic or roman numerals.."

Comment: sometimes a transistor is used in an unconventional way and there are applications where the base is kept floating like using the transistor as a sensor or using its avalanche breakdown like in the following:  http://cappels.org/dproj/simplest_LED_flasher/Simplest_LED_Flasher_Circuit.html .

Comment: Paul Ghobril: thanks, I tried to figure out the BJT's working mode from that circuit.

Comment: @SredniVashtar:  If it has a base it is a BJT - unless you have someone working with a MOSFET but calling the gate the base.  That kind of mix up is more common than you think.

Comment: It depends. On the transistor type and its packaging, for one thing. I'm old enough to remember scratching the black paint off an OC71 ( germanium transistor, PNP, in a black painted glass package) because I couldn't afford an OCP71 phototransistor. It worked pretty well with no base connection...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinary BJT is a low input impedance current driven device. If there's no connection to the base, then base-emitter diode forward conduction/leakage will quickly take the base potential down to the emitter potential. The transistor will be off.

For collector/emitter voltages within its ratings, no significant current will flow. For voltages outside the ratings, eventually the transistor will break down, and at a lower voltage than it would have done with the base physically shorted to the emitter, due to collector/base diode reverse leakage.

To get anything interesting happening in a transistor with an open control terminal, it has to be a FET. They are high impedance voltage driven devices. If you take the gate to a potential, it will persist at that potential for some time, due to the low leakage and finite capacitance of the gate to the other electrodes. If you have a way of injecting and removing charge from this gate capacitance, then you can use it to store data, both digital (on/off) and analogue (how much on), for some time depending on the leakage x capacitance time constant.

As Brain pointed out in comments, things can also be interesting with a phototransistor. As it happens, all transistors are phototransistors, but most are packaged in opaque packages so are not sensitive to light. Way back when germanium was still the most popular transistor material, the easiest way to obtain a phototransistor was to scrape the black paint off the glass-tube-packaged OC71. Light excitation allows a current to flow across the reverse biassed collector/base junction, which is then amplified by the transistor beta. This is the reason transistors are often used rather than diodes as photodetectors, a far higher output current. The price to pay is that they tend to be much slower than a diode.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed.

Comment: ... unless it's a phototransistor. Which is literally just a transistor in a clear package.

Comment: "will quickly take the base potential down to emitter potential" - no, the base will develop a voltage with respect to the emitter (of a few hundreds millivolts). It is predicted by theory and simulations but it might be tricky to measure (due to the internal resistance of the meter and AC coupling to nearby power lines)